# creating a list of lists and getting the last item of each list

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I've created a list in python which consists of 3 other lists. I can append integers to each of these lists and then print the last item of these lists. Here is the code:

```
L = [[] for i in range(3)]

L[0].append(1)
L[0].append(2)
L[0].append(3)
L[1].append(4)
L[1].append(5)
L[1].append(6)
L[2].append(7)
L[2].append(8)
L[2].append(9)

last = map (lambda x: x[-1], L)
print (last)
```

and here is the output:

```
[3, 6, 9]
```

Now I'm trying to write this code in Java, but since I'm new to Java, I have problem in appending items to each list and getting the last item of each list. I know that `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> listOLists = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();` will create a list of lists, but what should I do next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are good answers here already, but here is an option that is the closest I could match to your python example:

```
    List<List<Integer>> L = new ArrayList<>();
    L.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
    L.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
    L.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());

    L.get(0).add(1);
    L.get(0).add(2);
    L.get(0).add(3);
    L.get(1).add(4);
    L.get(1).add(5);
    L.get(1).add(6);
    L.get(2).add(7);
    L.get(2).add(8);
    L.get(2).add(9);

    int[] last = L.stream().mapToInt(x -> x.get(x.size() - 1)).toArray();
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(last));
```

Comment: Looks like Dan W beat me to it, though his option offers a slightly different method to get to the end result.

Comment: There are great answers here already, but this one is the closest answer to my code until now.

Answer (score 2):

```
 List<List<String>> listOfLists = new ArrayList<>();

     List<String> l1 = new ArrayList<>();
     l1.add("one");
     l1.add("two");
     listOfLists.add(l1);

     List<String> l2 = new ArrayList<>();
     l2.add("three");
     l2.add("four");
     listOfLists.add(l2);

     /*print last element of each list*/

     for(List list:listOfLists){
         System.out.println(list.get(list.size() - 1));
     }
```

Answer (score 2):

To expand on @Praveen's answer:

```
List<List<Integer>> listOLists = new ArrayList();

List<Integer> firstList = new ArrayList<>();
firstList.add(1);
firstList.add(2);
firstList.add(3);
listOLists.add(firstList);

List<Integer> secondList = new ArrayList<>();
secondList.add(4);
secondList.add(5);
secondList.add(6);
listOLists.add(secondList);

List<Integer> thirdList = new ArrayList<>();
thirdList.add(7);
thirdList.add(8);
thirdList.add(9);
listOLists.add(thirdList);

listOLists.forEach(l -> System.out.println(l.get(l.size() - 1)));
```

This prints out:

```
3
6
9
```

If you want it to print exactly how you have it in your Python example, change the last line to:

```
System.out.println(listOLists.stream().map(l -> l.get(l.size() - 1)).collect(Collectors.toList()));
....
[3, 6, 9]
```

This requires Java 8+.

Comment: Thanks for extending my answer @Dan. I edited my answer and then saw the same answer by you :)

Answer (score 2):

Also you can do it with the Arrays.asList() method. In this case you don't neet to type each time a fresh lines of code to add fresh values, but directly add them to an existing arrays wherever you'd like.

```
    List<Integer> firstList = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
    List<Integer> secondList = Arrays.asList(4, 5, 6);
    List<Integer> thirdList = Arrays.asList(7, 8, 9);

    List<List<Integer>> listOLists = Arrays.asList(firstList, secondList, thirdList);

    List <Integer> sv = new ArrayList<>();
    listOLists.forEach(l -> sv.add(l.get(l.size() - 1)));

    System.out.println(listOLists);
    System.out.println("The last indexes are " + sv);
```

The result is:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
The last indexes are [3, 6, 9]
```

Comment: This is probably as short it gets with Java.

Answer (score 1):

I have done this with Integers List. Please modify it to String List if needed.

```
List<List<Integer>> listOLists = new ArrayList();

    List<Integer> firstList = new ArrayList<>();
    firstList.add(1);
    firstList.add(2);
    firstList.add(3);
    listOLists.add(firstList);

    List<Integer> secondList = new ArrayList<>();
    secondList.add(4);
    secondList.add(5);
    secondList.add(6);
    listOLists.add(secondList);

    List<Integer> thirdList = new ArrayList<>();
    thirdList.add(7);
    thirdList.add(8);
    thirdList.add(9);
    listOLists.add(thirdList);

    System.out.println(listOLists); //prints whole listOfLists
    listOLists.forEach(l -> System.out.println(l.get(l.size()-1))); //prints only last elements
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't print the last item of each list, does it? I know that I can do this for each list one by one, for example: `System.out.println(firstList.get(firstList.size() -1))`, but how about something like `last = map (lambda x: x[-1], L)` in Python?

Comment: Updated the answer @helen